# Nuget restore without VS with package content installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, continuous-integration, nuget

I'm trying to configurate CI for my .Net project.

In CI script i'm use

```
nuget.exe restore mysolution.sln
```

But this command only download nuget packages in ./packages directory, not install content in  projects.

In Visual Studio I can use

```
Update-Package -reinstall -Project YourProjectName
```

or

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

both of this command reinstall packages whith it's content, not only download.
For example, the nuget package GDAL added file GdalConfiguration.cs in project after installation, but not after "nuget restore" command. Second example - package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, that added folder SqlServerTypes in project.

How can I fully reinstall pckages whithout VS by script? How do you solve this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried the "update" command for nuget.exe (perhaps after doing the "restore")?

Comment: which CI are you using? most CI have nuget built-in to restore your packages

Comment: @AmanB Thank's for comment! 
I'm using Gitlab CI.  I'm misunderstand, how CI can restore my packages itself?

Comment: @elgonzo Thank's for comment! Yes, I tried, no success. 
According to Leo Liu-MSFT - it is impossible to do what I want..

Comment: @Arseniy Had the exact same question about CI. I ended up adding a manual "copy" command to my ci/cd script :(( нугет говно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fully reinstall pckages without VS by script? How do you solve this problem?

I am afraid that you can not reinstall the nuget packages without Visual Studio. That because all those reinstall command line have to be executed on the Package Manager Console window and we could not use the Package manager console powershell outside visual studio, because **package manager console is providing is access to visual studio objects**:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1512

Those CI command line does not modify a project file or packages.config, that the reason why you use `nuget restore`, `nuget install` and `nuget update`, none of those command line modify the project file, check [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) for some more details:

[image]

Check [my other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429387/how-to-resolve-nuget-package-version-and-path-in-pre-build-event-of-a-project/46441058#46441058) for some helps.

Comment: This is little discourages me - how people use CI with this problem? They add all package files to each project in git? Very strange. But thank you again, I'm not wasting any more time!

Comment: "how people use CI with this problem? They add all package files to each project in git?"---Nuget packages(Or just to say the `\packages` folder should not add into the git) should not add into the git. But the content files needs to be added to git, that means those `GdalConfiguration.cs` and folder SqlServerTypes should be add to the git (That means the line `<Content Include="GdalConfiguration.vb" />` in the project file will be add to the git). When we pull the source and use nuget restore those nuget package to the `\packages` folder, and the path of those content file will will match.

Comment: Again, if above answer resolve your question, you can accept it as answer.  This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and we could close this thread, if not, please let me know your question now for free, I will keep follow.

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot about the check mark. Thank you for your detailed answer and help!

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT had exact same question about CI/CD. So if a nuget package adds jquery, or icon fonts, or images, or etc. to my web-app - I'm forced to add it to git. Grrrreeeeat. Microsoft being Microsoft.