# Reference DLL with NuGet dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Let's say I build a project named B as B.dll. Project B uses several NuGet packages. B.dll is referenced in another project A. How can I automatically add the referenced NuGet dependencies to project A?
I don't want to run a NuGet server.

Comment: Why do you need to add reference assemblies? since B.dll includes nuget assemblies A.dll also includes that assemblies

Comment: You say you don't want to run a NuGet server. Does that imply that some of these are your own local NuGet packages?

Comment: Because I need access to these assemblies in B.dll as well.

Comment: @John, no, I don't create nupkg files from the DLL. I only build DLLs.

Comment: if they're in the same solution, just make it a project reference. The build system automatically copies all of B's output, which includes the nuget dlls. If it's not in the same solution, then you can use a local folder or network share as a nuget feed without to set up some server software (although there are some nuget servers that are easy to set up)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I automatically add the referenced NuGet dependencies to project A? I don't want to run a NuGet server.

It depends on where you want to add those NuGet dependencies for the project A, if you add them to the project A's output, you can just use a copy command line in the build event to copy those dependencies to the project A`s output, like:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(SolutionDir)\...\bin\...\"
```

If you want to add those dependencies to the References node of project A **automatically**, this is almost impossible. If you want to automate that, you have to do this operations via NuGet CLI. Since Install package on NuGet CLI will not modify the reference of project, so we could not automate the operation install package to update the reference of the project.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429387/how-to-resolve-nuget-package-version-and-path-in-pre-build-event-of-a-project/46441058#46441058) for some more details.

So, it seems unlikely if you want to fully automated to add the referenced NuGet dependencies to project A. As a workaround, you can set the path of the `\packages` folder of project B to the NuGet source, then you can add those NuGet package to the project A with NuGet package management UI, so that you do not need to run a NuGet server.