# how to write command lines for install packages in package manager console of vs2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

For vs2017, I run the install-package in package manager console for installing packages. And I find there are about two steps. The first step is to install packages and the second step is to add dlls related to the project file. What I want to know is how to write some command lines based on nuget, dotnet, and so on to finish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to write command lines for install packages in package manager console of vs2017

If you want to write your own nuget command line, you can use the NuGet API in Visual Studio.

Starting from NuGet 3.3+, NuGet exports the following services all of which reside in the NuGet.VisualStudio namespace in the NuGet.VisualStudio.dll assembly:

- `IRegistryKey`: Method to retrieve a value from a registry subkey.
- `IVsPackageInstaller`: Methods to install NuGet packages into projects.
- `IVsPackageInstallerEvents`: Events for package install/uninstall.
- `IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents`: Batch events for package
  install/uninstall.

  ...

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio) for some more details.

Besides, you can get more source code of nuget command on the github:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I learn about i can install packages by nuget cli, but i find that if i use nuget command line to install packages. It works. But how to add dll file reference to project file by command line. i don't solve it.

Comment: @Jianfeng, you could not add dll file reference to project file by command line nuget install, because NuGet CLI does not modify a project file or packages.config, you can check my another thread for more details:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429387/how-to-resolve-nuget-package-version-and-path-in-pre-build-event-of-a-project/46441058#46441058.